# FURTHER CLARIFICATION: How to correctly write Try..Finally..Except statements?

Tags: delphi, try-finally, try-except

RE: [How to correctly write Try..Finally..Except statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601147/how-to-correctly-write-try-finally-except-statements)

I'm still confused by the OP's original question. Specifically, the last line of the procedure (outside of the try..finally..end) that reads "Screen.Cursor:=crDefault".

My understanding is that any exceptions raised inside a try..except|finally..end block *WILL* execute the code after the "end" of the "try".

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Obj: TSomeObject;
begin
  Screen.Cursor := crHourGlass;

  Obj := TSomeObject.Create;
  try
    // do something
  finally
    Obj.Free;
  end;
  Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
end;
```

In the above example, I don't see any reason why "Screen.Cursor:=crDefault" would not be executed. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

As a further example, I've compiled this little bit of code to help illustrate. When the code is ran, THREE (3) ShowMessage() dialogs will be presented. The first "Exception Raised" and the second "finally" and the third "at end".

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   try
      try
         showMessage(format('%s', [12]));
      except
         showMessage('Exception raised');
      end;
   finally
      showMessage('finally');
   end;
   showMessage('at end');
end;
```

So, I'm confused on why his "Screen.Cursor:=crDefault" isn't being ran, in it's original form and code. Can someone please elaborate?

Answer (score 11):

The code you posted seems to work fine, because you're able to handle all possibilities. Try changing it somewhat though, so that there's an exception raised your code doesn't handle:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  try
    try
      raise Exception.Create('42');
    except
      on E: EDivByZero do
        ShowMessage('DivByZero');
    end;
  finally
    ShowMessage('Finally');
  end;
  ShowMessage('Got here');
end;
```

Run this, and you'll see `Finally`, then the exception for [`42`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_%28number%29), but no `Got here` message. This is because the exception took you out of the current block, the stack is unwound, and the code from the `end` of the finally to the end of the procedure never executes.

Move the final `ShowMessage` call from where it is to inside the `finally` and run again.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  try
    try
      raise Exception.Create('42');
    except
      on E: EDivByZero do
        ShowMessage('DivByZero');
    end;
  finally
    ShowMessage('Finally');
    ShowMessage('Got here');
  end;
  ShowMessage('Will never get here');
end;
```

You'll now see both calls to `ShowMessage` in the `finally` block, one after the other, but not the one after the `finally` block's `end;`. Code inside the `finally` block is guaranteed to execute, while code beyond it may or may not.

To make it even more clear, the presence of the `try..except` block can be removed:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  try
    raise Exception.Create('42');
  finally
    ShowMessage('Finally');
    ShowMessage('Got here');
  end;
  ShowMessage('Will never get here');
end;
```

The entire purpose of the `try..finally` block is to ensure that code inside the `finally` section will execute before the procedure ends.

Comment: I think I understand better with your example.

Basically, if the "except" has an "on" clause and if the Exception is not handled by the "on" clause, that's when bad things happen and the code in the procedure, after the try...end isn't executed.

So, anytime a try..except..end is utilized *AND* an "on" clause is added to catch specific exceptions; these code blocks need to be audited to ensure that any exceptions *NOT* caught by the "except...on" are handled correctly.

Comment: @VinK: Not quite. If there's no `except` clause at all, bad things can happen and cause the same problem. Remove the `try..except..end` entirely, but leave the `raise` statement; you'll still see that the code between the end of the `finally` and the end of the procedure don't execute. The entire purpose of the `finally` block is to *make sure that the code executes*. The code after it *may not run*.

Comment: Got ya. Thank you for clarifying this behavior.

Comment: @Jerry: Thanks. I admit it was an afterthought; I changed it from the poster's `12` during an edit. :-) I hope that wasn't the actual reason for the upvote, though. :-(

Comment: Great answer, just being "sarcastic"

Answer (score 2):

In Delphi, the `finally` block doesn't really handle the exception that occured in the `try` block. It only guarantees that the code in the `finally` block will always be executed, whether an exception occured or not in the `try` block. If an exception really happened in there, it won't get caught. And when an exception didn't get caught, you know what happened to the code below it.

To catch the exception that might be occured, use the `try...except...` block instead. You can combine these two construct to do those two action: (1) guarantee the execution some piece of code, and (2) catch the exceptions which might occured. The common usage is like this:

```
try
  try
    // do something that might cause an exception.
  finally
    // do something that must be executed WHATEVER happened.
  end;
except
  // do something ONLY IF an exception has occured.
end;
```

So, you should change your code and move the `Screen.Cursor := crDefault;` inside the `finally` block. In addition, add the `try...except...` block to surround the `try...finally...` block. Like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Obj: TSomeObject;
begin
  Screen.Cursor := crHourGlass;
  Obj := TSomeObject.Create;
  try
    try
      // do something.
    finally
      Obj.Free;
      Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
    end;
  except
    ShowMessage('An error has occured!');
  end;
end;
```

Or, if you are not sure that the code `Obj := TSomeObject.Create;` is safe enough, you should add the second `try...finally...` block to surround it, like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Obj: TSomeObject;
begin
  Screen.Cursor := crHourGlass;
  try
    try
      Obj := TSomeObject.Create;
      try
        // do something.
      finally
        Obj.Free;
      end;
    finally
      Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
    end;
  except
    ShowMessage('An error has occured!');
  end;
end;
```

There, hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually catch the exception. In this case, upon exception, the "finally" block of code will execute, and then the exception will unwind the stack.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The exception is caught and will say "Exception raised", it will then say "Finally" and then "at the end".

All 3 of these ShowMessage() dialogs will be shown a result of the attempt to perform the format(), which will generate the exception.

In short, the final opertion in the procedure is executed in both examples. So, I don't understand why the final line in the procedure would need to be included within a try..finally..end

Comment: You have "except" expression in second piece of code, but don't have it in original code. "except" is what catches exception, not "finally"