# DBGrid data not updated until restarting app or DB connection

Tags: sql, delphi, firebird

I am using Delphi 10.2.3 and Firebird 2.5.8. I have small table with 2 fields (id & text) which I edit within of a subform and use the data on my mainform. On the subform I use `DBGrid` & `DBNavigator`. On each use, I create the form and destroy it afterwards.

On my subform I can see each time the updated data. After closing the subform I refresh my list within of my mainform but

```
SELECT Id,Text FROM Tbl_Test
```

shows me only the old data.

I get the updated data only after restarting my program. Any idea what I could have done wrong? Btw. isql.exe also doesn't update the data. I have to restart isql. I tested Firebird 2.5.6 too - no difference in the behaviour.

I am using `IBDataBase` and `IBTable`for the DBGrid and `IBquery`.

When I disconnect the `IBDatabase`and reconnect then I get the updated data. Isn't there a better way?

Comment: what transaction and connection objects does subform use? what transaction and connection objects does the grid use? If to shoot blindly to the stars, your grid's transaction seem to be of "snapshot" kind, not "read committed" kind, so it does not care about later transactions made changes. When you restart the program or when you restart IBDatabase connection - you kill that old transaction and start fresh new one, which being started after the subform's tx committed does see the changes. All in all, read some ABC books about database apps in Delphi, especially transactions-related chapters

Comment: I had to `Transaction.commit`in my main form before I could access the new data. Problem solved

Comment: yeah, so you have to make up your mind which kind of transactions they gonna be and what way you would manage them.

Comment: I "inherited" the software - so I am fighting to understand code, structure, ...

Comment: Uh-oh.... My condolences. I know how convoluted mess can grow without boring explicit transaction handling. Maybe your proper solution would had been to make grid's tx RC type not snapshot type. But.... that can have unwanted effects on other parts of the form. At least you do have two distinct transactions for the two forms, it could be worse...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably you have two transactions, one to populate the grid and another to make changes in the subform.

Then, the grid's transaction is probably

- set up as SNAPSHOT kind, not READ COMMITTED kind
- is not restarted after the subform's tx "commits" changed data

That way this transaction refuses to see changes introduced after it was started. But when you re-connect to the database you implicitly roll-back that tx and start another newer grid's tx.

If so, you would have to either change the grid's tx to RC kind (proving it would not break anything else in the form) or manually restart that transaction to let it see the newer data.